# Make MapView display normal Apple Maps when I don't have a tile in my MKTileOverlay set

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am working on an iOS map that uses a "custom" map, stored completley in my application so it can always be accessed offline. I am using a custom MKTileOverlay URL to my local file store to make this happen, etc.

However, as my application's map only covers a small geographic area, I would like to have have the MapView display the standard Apple Map in such cases. When I overlay the map and set "canReplaceMapContent" to true, I just get a blank white space for map tiles that aren't present.

I don't really want to set canReplaceMapContent to FALSE, because *most* of the time a user will be using my (custom) map, so I wouldn't want the overhead of rendering the Apple map that would be completely covered.

Is there any way I can return a "nil" to a function or something to tell MapKit to not use the TileOverlay, and just use the regular Apple map instead?

Answer (score 0):

No, but here's an idea: have two `MKMapView`s with the same frame, one with your custom map and `canReplaceMapContent = YES` and the other without and `NO`. You can hide one and show the other, transferring annotations if necessary, and you might be able to produce a convincing swap.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. On kind of that vein - I was thinking about if I could flip canReplaceMapContent on and off, depending on if the view was exclusivity within my offline region or not.